# How to split in Mitos.is

Tags: mitos.is

Everyone is doing this thing were you split and then feed your farther half until its almost the same size again.
I tried to do this, but every time I do...  my origin point changes.
and I'm just tossing a piece back and forth between my two half's.
So.. how do they do it?

Apparently you can do it in agar.io to.

Answer (score 1):

Well it turns out... you just have to hold 'W' as apposed to tapping it.
then it will not switch back and forth like that.  And you can give all your mass to one half.